# Add a run time argument in a Flink job which can be submitted via Flink UI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Job which periodically reads some data from S3. The period is currently hardcoded in the S3 source function and I can only change it with a code change followed by re-deploy. I want to introduce a run time argument to update the period directly from the job UI. Is there an approach to do so?

I checked out ParameterTool, Commons CLI and Argparse4j but all of them have support for passing args from a file / command line or system properties. None of it has support for passing argument directly through UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.